Turning Io into a electrical generator
Ok, so a while ago, I found out that Io's interaction with Jupiter's magnetic field produces around 3 million amperes at around 400,000 volts. if a hunk of rock can produce that much energy, that surly we could do better if we just turned Io into a giant iron coil, with the radius of Io, and a wire diameter of 1 cm. Now the question is, how many joules can we produce before the coil is fragmented into a ring by Jupiter's gravity when it enters the Roche limit?

While Agnius shows that there is a bit of a problem with using an iron coil with a lot of windings, we could of course use fewer windings or some suitable superconductor (borrowed from the thought experiment department). So then the question is how much energy can be extracted, and that is relatively simple to estimate:
If the coil extracts energy from the orbital energy of Io, the total energy that can be extracted will be the difference between the current energy and the energy at the Roche limit. The Roche limit for a rigid Io-mass object around Jupiter is $r_1=R_{Io}\sqrt[3]{2M_{Jupiter}/M_{Io}} = 1821.6\times \sqrt[3]{2\times 1.898\cdot 10^{27}/8.93\cdot 10^{22}}= 63,573$ km. So lowering it from the current orbit at $r_0=421,700$ km would extract $GM_{Jupiter}M_{Io}(1/r_1 - 1/r_0) = 1.511\cdot 10^{32}$ Joule.
That is a lot - nearly the gravitational binding energy of Earth - but still just a few days of the Sun's energy output.

We can relatively easy calculate number of turns in such enormous coil if we model single coil loop as a torus and imagine that coil is simply $N$ such torus wire rings. In this case IO "converted" into coil would have (based on torus volume):
$$N=\frac {M_{IO}}{2\pi^2~\rho_{iron}~R_{IO}~r_{wire}^2}=\frac {10^{22} kg}{7.874 g/cm^3~2\pi^2 \cdot 1821 km \cdot (0.5 cm)^2} \approx 10^{15} \tag 1$$ number of wire loops !
Considering that coil total resistivity will be $$R=\rho L/A\tag 2$$, (here $\rho$ is specific resistivity, $A$ wire cross-section) where wire length is about $L=N~2\pi R=10^{15} \times 2\pi~\times 1821 km = 10^{19} km\tag 3$ in total, which would give, as per (2) : $$R=(10^{−7} ~\Omega \cdot m × 10^{19} km)/(\pi×(0.5cm)^2) \approx 12~EΩ=10^{19}Ω \tag 4$$ coil total resistance !
Such iron coil resistance corresponds to a resistance of hard rubber stick of $100~m$ in length.
Needless to say that it will function as almost a perfect insulator. So, the current will not go through the coil or electrical breakdown may happen.
In the both scenarios this is not what a typical coil inductance was meant to be, because nobody uses insulators for them. So I doubt if this model is anyhow feasible or in any use.
